# How do I read sheet two of an xlsx file with PHPExcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel, import-from-excel

I know how to read my xlsx spreadsheet and loop through the first sheet.

It has 5 sheets and I am having trouble getting to any other than the first.

Here is the code I am using which was straight from the documentation.
You can see I tried to utilize setActiveSheet, but that threw the error `Call to undefined method PHPExcel::setActiveSheet()`.

**Code**:

```
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("cmt_school_data.xlsx");
//$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheet(1);
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

echo '<table border=1>' . "\n";

foreach ($objWorksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {

  echo '<tr>' . "\n";

  $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();

  // This loops all cells, even if it is not set.
  // By default, only cells that are set will be iterated.
  $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);

  foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
    echo '<td>' . $cell->getValue() . '</td>' . "\n";
  }

  echo '</tr>' . "\n";

}

echo '</table>' . "\n";
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Ok...the names are deceiving.  setActiveSheetIndex also does a get so the solution was this

```
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("cmt_school_data.xlsx");
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
//objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
echo '<table border=1>' . "\n";
foreach ($objWorksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
  echo '<tr>' . "\n";
  $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
  $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false); // This loops all cells,
                                                     // even if it is not set.
                                                     // By default, only cells
                                                     // that are set will be
                                                     // iterated.
  foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
    echo '<td>' . $cell->getValue() . '</td>' . "\n";
  }
  echo '</tr>' . "\n";
}
echo '</table>' . "\n";
```

Comment: As you've already discovered, setActiveSheet() doesn't exist: setActiveSheetIndex() and setActiveSheetIndexByName() are the two methods available for changing the active sheet.

Comment: Where can I download this library?

Comment: What about using $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheetByName("sheetName"); ?

Answer (score 14):

```
<?php

/** Include path **/
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '../../../Classes/');

/** PHPExcel_IOFactory */
include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';


$inputFileType = 'Excel5';
//  $inputFileType = 'Excel2007';
//  $inputFileType = 'Excel2003XML';
//  $inputFileType = 'OOCalc';
//  $inputFileType = 'Gnumeric';
$inputFileName = './sampleData/example1.xls';

echo 'Loading file ',pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME),' using IOFactory with a defined reader type of ',$inputFileType,'<br />';
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
echo 'Loading all WorkSheets<br />';
$objReader->setLoadAllSheets();
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);


echo '<hr />';

echo $objPHPExcel->getSheetCount(),' worksheet',(($objPHPExcel->getSheetCount() == 1) ? '' : 's'),' loaded<br /><br />';
$loadedSheetNames = $objPHPExcel->getSheetNames();
foreach($loadedSheetNames as $sheetIndex => $loadedSheetName) {
    echo **$sheetIndex**,' -> ',$loadedSheetName,'<br />';
    $sheetData = $objPHPExcel->**getSheet**(**$sheetIndex**)->toArray(null,true,true,true);
    var_dump($sheetData);

}?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been too late for the answer. But I find solution as below.

```
//load library - EXCEL
$this->load->library('excel');
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('./folder/exceldata.xls');

//Get How Many Sheets in your Excel file.
echo $objPHPExcel->getSheetCount();
```

Then, to access a sheet by its index, use the getSheet() method. Note that sheets are indexed from 0.
e.g.

```
//Retrieve the **1st 'tab' worksheet** e.g. called 'Sheet 1'
$worksheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
```

So in your case, if you want to read only Sheet-2 then,

```
$worksheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(1);
```

OR to read all Sheets from your Excel file, you have to use foreach loop as below.

```
    foreach($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet)
    {
      $highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
      $highestColumn = $worksheet->getHighestColumn();
      //echo $highestRow;
      //echo $highestColumn;
      //die();
      for($row=2; $row<=$highestRow; $row++)
      {
        $column1 = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $row)->getValue();
        $column2= $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->getValue();

        $finaldata[] = array(
            'data1'   =>    trim($column1),
            'data2'   =>    trim($column2),
          );
      }
    }
    /*echo "<pre>";
    echo count($finaldata);
    print_r($finaldata);
    die();*/
```

Answer (score 0):

How do I read **multiple worksheet from a single excel file** using PHPExcel. [ using Codeigniter 3.1.11 ]

[multiple worksheet from a single excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4mwr.png)
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4mwr.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyPQz.png

Source Code
// Bulk upload
function bulk_upload()
{
$output = array();

```
    $file_upload    = $_FILES['bulk_karvy_file']['tmp_name'];

    if (isset($file_upload) && !empty($file_upload)){ 

        //You can add directly the Composer Autoloder in your controller: 
        require FCPATH . 'vendor/autoload.php';

        try{   
            $db_spreadsheet = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file_upload);   
        }   
        catch (Exception $e){
            die('Error loading file "' . pathinfo($file_upload, PATHINFO_BASENAME) . '": '.@$e->getMessage()); 
        }   

        // sheet list
        $sheetListArray = ["Ann B","Ann C","Ann E","Ann F"];

        $sheetData = [];
        
        $sheetCount = $db_spreadsheet->getSheetCount(); 

        if(is_null($sheetCount))
        {}
        else{

            // Read Excel Sheet
            for ($i = 0; $i < $sheetCount; $i++) 
            {
                $sheet  = $db_spreadsheet->getSheet($i);
                $sheetN = $sheet->getTitle();

                if(in_array($sheetN,$sheetListArray))
                {
                    $sheetData[] = array(
                        'data'    => $sheet->toArray(null, true, true, true),
                        'file'    => $sheetN,
                        'total'   => count($sheet->toArray(null, true, true, true))
                    );
             
                }

            
            }

            // Read all Sheets from your Excel file, you have to use foreach loop
            foreach($sheetData as $val)
            {
                $N = @$val['total'];      

                for($i=2; $row <= $N; $i++)
                {
                        $db_ch= 64;
                        $sl_no          = trim($val['data'][$i][chr(++$db_ch)]);
                        if(empty($sl_no)){break;}
                        $ref_no         = trim($val['data'][$i][chr(++$db_ch)]);
                        $remark         = trim($val['data'][$i][chr(++$db_ch)]);
                        $dep_slip_no    = trim($val['data'][$i][chr(++$db_ch)]);
                        $inst_no        = str_pad(trim($val['data'][$i][chr(++$db_ch)]),6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
                        $amount         = trim($val['data'][$i][chr(++$db_ch)]);
                        $drawee_name    = trim($val['data'][$i][chr(++$db_ch)]);
                        $sch_code       = str_pad(trim($val['data'][$i][chr(++$db_ch)]),3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
                        $ufc_code       = trim($val['data'][$i][chr(++$db_ch)]);
                        $acc_no         = trim($val['data'][$i][chr(++$db_ch)]);
                        $ihno           = trim($val['data'][$i][chr(++$db_ch)]);
                        $trno           = trim($val['data'][$i][chr(++$db_ch)]);
                        $tr_dt          = str_replace('/', '-',trim($val['data'][$i][chr(++$db_ch)]));
                        $value_date     = str_replace('/', '-',trim($val['data'][$i][chr(++$db_ch)]));
                        $branch         = trim($val['data'][$i][chr(++$db_ch)]);
                        $file_name      = trim($val['data'][$i][chr(++$db_ch)]);
                        $category       = trim($val['data'][$i][chr(++$db_ch)]);
                        $upload_type    = trim($val['data'][$i][chr(++$db_ch)]);
                        $fl_name        = @$val['file'];
                        $fl_name_id     = @$db_fn->id;
                        $created_at     = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                        $updated_at     = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");   [chr(++$db_ch)]);
                }
            }

        } // end of else

        

        
    }

    echo json_encode($sheetData);
}
```