# PHPExcel - member function getRowIterator() on null

Tags: php, phpexcel, spreadsheet

I wrote an API that imports an xlsx file. That works fine.

In next function I wrote a logic that needs to extract that file but I don't know what is causing this error:

> Call to a member function getRowIterator() on null

My first call:

```
public function importXlsx($fileLocation)
{
    $reader = IOFactory::createReader('Xlsx');
    $reader->setReadDataOnly(true);
    $spreadsheet = $reader->load($fileLocation);

    $this->importSheet($spreadsheet, 'One', function(User $user) {
        $user->setType();
        return $user;
    });

    $this->importSheet($spreadsheet, 'Two', function(User $user) {
        $user->setType2();
        return $user;
    });


    die('done');

}
```

My second call:

```
 private function importSheet($spreadsheet, $sheetName, callable $additionalManipulation = null)
{

    $worksheet = $spreadsheet->getSheetByName($sheetName);

    $columnMappings = [
        'First Name' => 'firstName',
        'Surname' => 'lastName',
        'Email' => 'email',
    ];

    $headerColumns = null;

    $data = [];

    foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $index => $row) {

        $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
        $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(FALSE);
        $rowData = [];
        foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
            $rowData[]= $cell->getValue();
        }

        if($index == 1) {
            $headerColumns = $rowData;
        } else {

            $rowData = array_combine($headerColumns, $rowData);
            $data[$index] =$rowData;
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you print  the  $worksheet i thinking $worksheet is null

Comment: Yes it is. I don't know how that is possible? My document has data and it's imported. @Shibon

Comment: What is this $spreadsheet ???

Comment: $spreadsheet = $reader->load($fileLocation); it's this one, that getting my xlsx file in other function. @Shibon

Comment: Please add that code too.. in question

Comment: Updated! @Shibon

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170275/how-do-i-read-sheet-two-of-an-xlsx-file-with-phpexcel